# How to turn several variables with numbered names into a dictionary using the numbers as keys?

Tags: python

I have this code as example:

```
list100 = [1, 1, 1]
list200 = [2, 2, 2]
save_dict = dict()
for i in [100, 200]:
   save_dict[i] = 'list' + str(i)
```

Now `save_dict` will be `{100: 'list100', 200: 'list200'}`.

What I want is `{100: [1, 1, 1], 200: [2, 2, 2]}`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Why not just `lists = {100: [1, 1, 1], 200: [2, 2, 2]}`?  What I mean is, using strings to access variables by name is a code smell and you should rethink your problem statement to avoid this.

Comment: I do not know how to explain why I need this.  A long story. First I will generate a lot of numpy arrays around 2000. Then I want to use numpy.savez to store them in a single file. Therefore I need to put these 2000 lists into a dictionary but I do not find a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `globals` for this:

```
list100=[1,1,1]
list200=[2,2,2]
save_dict = dict()
for i in [100, 200]:
   save_dict[i]=globals()[f'list{i}'] #brings the global variable that is assigned of `f'list{i}'`
```